# Return type of Database.query(Query) isn't Array?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, skygear

While working on Skygear JS SDK, is the query returning an Array?

```
  readDummy: function(){
        const Test = skygear.Record.extend('test_test');
        const Query = new skygear.Query(Test);

        skygear.publicDB.query(Query).then((records) => {
          console.log(records.constructor === Array); // return false
          console.log(JSON.stringify(records[0])); //do display correctly
          //{"_id":"test_test/b9633d1a-ff3c-491b-82f3-93c8cefb5313","_access":[{"public":true,"level":"read"}],"content":"Hello World"}
        }, (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });

      },
```

Comment: post ` console.log(JSON.stringify(records[0]));` also

Comment: Their docs say it should be an array. Why does it matter if the constructor doesn't exactly match `Array`?

Comment: I am passing Records to Polymer's dom-repeat, it throws error of "expected array for `items`, found [r, _overallCount: undefined]"

Comment: but isn't `QueryResult` extends `Array`?

Comment: Try `QueryResult instanceof Array`, but that's just for testing, it won't fix anything.

Comment: @RobG There's always good old [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#instanceof_vs_isArray). Like you said, useful for debugging but it seems *"Polymer's dom-repeat"* is picky about what you pass to it

Answer (score 3):

Appears the object is actually a [`QueryResult`](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/skygeario/skygear-SDK-JS/class/lib/query_result.js~QueryResult.html) which extends `Array`.

Whatever you're passing the object to appears to be too particular about the exact type.

You could try this

```
Array.from(records)
```

to make it a native array.

Comment: [*Type*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types) or [*builtinTag*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring) (formerly called `[[Class]]`)? Arrays are Object type, but instances of Array. I guess without seeing the actual code it's hard to tell which. ;-)